# Python script is not working on linux cluster

Tags: python, scripting, nonetype, abaqus

I am trying to do a parametric study in abaqus and I am using a python script to investigate different models. In the post-processing phase of the problem I am interested in one particular value (the value of the J integral) at the at the end of the simulation.
When I run my script on my own PC it is working (it loops through all iterations) but when I try to run it on the university's linux cluster it always quits at the same point (at the 16th iteration), with the following error:
`TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

The problematic piece of code is the following:

```
#Post processing
odbObject=session.openOdb(name=NameJob+'.odb', readOnly=False)
step1=odbObject.steps['Step-1']
pickedSet='CRACK_FRONT'
JIntValues=step1.historyRegions['ElementSet  ALL ELEMENTS'].historyOutputs['J at J_INT_CRACK-1_'+pickedSet+'_Contour_1'].data
JValueAtEnd=JIntValues[-1][-1]
```

The aforementioned error occurs at the last line of the attached code.
The problem (to me) is very strange because I think that if there were a problem with the value extraction it should occur on my PC as well.

Comment: could you show us the output of JIntValues?

Comment: JIntValues is an 11-by-2 matrix, representing the data points in the history output. Here is an example output:
((0.00999999977648258, 4.12362851420767e-06), (0.0199999995529652, 1.64945140568307e-05), (0.0350000001490116, 5.05144489579834e-05), (0.0575000010430813, 0.000136337461299263), (0.0912500023841858, 0.000343356485245749), (0.141874998807907, 0.000830025179311633), (0.217812493443489, 0.00195634365081787), (0.331718742847443, 0.00453753070905805), (0.502578139305115, 0.0104156574234366), (0.758867204189301, 0.0237471275031567), (1.0, 0.0412362851202488))